# asp.net MVC AddUserToRole error: 'webpages_UsersInRoles' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, roles, simplemembership

I've looked at a lot of questions that dealt with "IDENTITY_INSERT is ON" but I either can't seem to find one that helps me with my situation, or I'm new enough that I just don't understand how to fix it. So I apologize if this is a duplicate.

I am getting the following error when my code tries to run `Roles.AddUserToRole(UserName, RoleName);` I'm not sure what I did because I'm pretty sure I had this working at one time.

`An explicit value for the identity column in table 'webpages_UsersInRoles' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.`

I've been using a combo of the following tutorials:
http://tutlane.com/tutorial/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-membership-provider-to-create-users-roles-mapping-roles-to-users
http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2648/working-with-roles-in-aspnet-mvc-4

**Account Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Transactions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet;
using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth;
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using AccountModule_Attempt_5.Filters;
using AccountModule_Attempt_5.Models;

namespace AccountModule_Attempt_5.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //ROLES///

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult DisplayAllRole() 
        {
            IEnumerable<Role> ListRoles;
            using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
            {
                ListRoles = db.Roles.ToList();
            }
            return View(ListRoles);
        }

        [NonAction]
        public List<SelectListItem> GetAll_Users()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> listuser = new List<SelectListItem>();
            listuser.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "select", Value = "0" });
            using (UsersContext db = new UsersContext())
            {
                foreach (var item in db.UserProfiles)
                {
                    listuser.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item.UserName, Value = item.UserName });
                }
            }
            return listuser;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult RoleAddToUser()
        {
            SelectList list = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles()); 
            ViewBag.Roles = list;

            return View();
        }


        //Add User to Roll (adds multiple roles) http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2648/working-with-roles-in-aspnet-mvc-4
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult RoleAddToUser(string RoleName, string UserName)
        {

            if (Roles.IsUserInRole(UserName, RoleName))
            {
                ViewBag.ResultMessage = "This user already has the role specified !";
            }
            else
            {
                **Roles.AddUserToRole(UserName, RoleName);** //This is the line that errors out.
                ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Username added to the role succesfully !";
            }

            SelectList list = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles());
            ViewBag.Roles = list;
            return View();
        }


        //Method for getting UserName by UserID : Here we Created GetUserName_BY_UserID Method for getting Users name from UserID and this Method is created inside Account Controller.
    public string GetUserName_BY_UserID(int UserId)
        {
        using (UsersContext context = new UsersContext())
        {
        var UserName = (from UP in context.UserProfiles
        where UP.UserId == UserId
        select UP.UserName).SingleOrDefault();
        return UserName;
        }


}
```

**View**

```
@model AccountModule_Attempt_5.Models.AssignRoleVM

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RoleAddToUser";
}


<h2>Role Add to User</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("RoleAddToUser", "Account"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="message-success">@ViewBag.ResultMessage</div>
    <p>
        Username : @Html.TextBox("UserName")
        Role Name: @Html.DropDownList("RoleName", ViewBag.Roles as SelectList)

    </p>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}


@*<h2>RoleAddToUser</h2>
<link href="~/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div>
        @ViewBag.ResultMessage
    </div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>AssignRoleVM</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RoleName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleName, new SelectList(Model.RolesList, "Value", "Text"),
new { style = "width:200px", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RoleName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserID, new SelectList(Model.Userlist, "Value", "Text"),
new { style = "width:200px", @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserID)
        </div>
        <br />
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Assign" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}*@
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**MODELS**
**UserProfile**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AccountModule_Attempt_5.Models
{
    [Table("UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string EmailId { get; set; }

        [Required]       
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }  
    }

}
```

**AccountModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace AccountModule_Attempt_5.Models
{
    public class UsersContext : DbContext
    {
        public UsersContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<webpages_UsersInRoles> webpages_UsersInRole { get; set; }
        //public DbSet<RegisterModel> UserProfiles { get; set; }
        //public DbSet<RegisterModel>Users { get; set; }
       // public DbSet<UsersRole> UsersRoles { get; set; }   
    }

    [Table("webpages_UsersInRoles")]
    public class webpages_UsersInRoles
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        public int RoleId { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegisterExternalLoginModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "User name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public string ExternalLoginData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**AssignRoleVM**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace AccountModule_Attempt_5.Models
{
    public class AssignRoleVM
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = " Select Role Name")]
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Select UserName")]
        public string UserID { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem> Userlist { get; set; }
        public List<SelectListItem> RolesList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Role**

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace AccountModule_Attempt_5.Models
{

    [Table("webpages_Roles")]
    public class Role
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Enter Role name")]
        //[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        public string RoleName { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what other code you need me to include, so tell me what would help and I'll include it. I've got the following Models:
Account, AssignRoleVM, Customer, Role, UserProfile 
I am also using Entity Framework 6.0 and MVC 4.5

Comment: That is a lot of code. Perhaps you should only post the part of code that has the issue.

Comment: @CodingYoshi Thanks for the suggestion. I've removed everything that doesn't have to do with Adding Users to Roles and bolded the code that is throwing the error.

Comment: Try and see if this works Roles.AddUsersToRoles(new []  {UserName}, new[] {RoleName});

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately, that didn't make a difference. I still get the same error.

Comment: Probably ASP .NET Identity tried to insert into identity fields. Check your `webpages_UsersInRoles` table, disable all Identity specifications there either by SSMS (converting identity column to regular int) or executing this query first: `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles ON`.

Comment: Can I do this inside a model? I'm using code first migration. My understanding is if I make a change to the database using SSMS, it will cause problems with my migration, is this correct? I've updated my question to include the models in case there is something inside there that needs to change.